# Is there an alternative for Page.ParseControl in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, parsecontrol

I have written a class library function that parses a string to a control. It takes the current page and uses page.ParseControl to parse the string as a control.

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = (System.Web.UI.Page) HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
System.Web.UI.Control ctrl = page.ParseControl(str);
```

It works fine in most scenarios except when the caller of this function is an Ajax Web Service in which case I am getting the following error: Unable to cast object of type 'HandlerWrapperWithSession' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page'. I am obviously getting this error because the CurrentHandler is not of type Page, but I need a Page object to call ParseControl.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla 
I am using the parseControl method to see if the markup in the string is valid. I am also checking for certain tags that I am filtering out.

Comment: Would it suffice to simply do: `Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page`.  This would result in `page == null` when it wasn't really a page.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Now I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
It really makes me wonder why parseControl is not static.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
Page p = new Page();
Control ctrl = p.ParseControl(str);
```